# How can I get radioButton value in FormCollection using ajax in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I have a action method which has a parameter FormCollection. In the form There are 2 radio buttons as below

```
@Html.RadioButton("radioSource", "Yes", true, new { id = "radioMoveAll", data_toggle = "tooltip", data_placement = "right", title = "Click to select", htmlAttributes }) Yes
@Html.RadioButton("radioSource", "No", false, new { id = "radioMoveAll", data_toggle = "tooltip", data_placement = "right", title = "Click to select", htmlAttributes })  No
```

My action method as follows passing form collection as a parameter by serializing in ajax code.

```
 public ActionResult StructureMove(FormCollection  form)
    {
        Structure sourceStructure = new Structure();
        sourceStructure = (Structure)HttpContext.Session["Return-Source-Structure"];


        HttpContext.Session["Form"] = form;
        HttpContext.Session["Source-Structure"] = sourceStructure;                       
        string selectedNode = sourceStructure.Code;
        string returnStructure = "";           

        StructureToMove stm = (StructureToMove)HttpContext.Session["StructureMoveObject"];
        var form1 = (FormCollection)HttpContext.Session["Form"];

        if (HttpContext.Request.Form["radioSource"].HasValue())
        {
            stm.MoveAll = HttpContext.Request.Form["radioSource"]=="Yes"?true:false;
        }
        if (HttpContext.Request.Form["chkreturnToSource"].HasValue())
        {
            stm.ReturnToDestination = HttpContext.Request.Form.GetValues("chkreturnToSource")[0] == "true" ? true:false;
        }
        .....
    }
```

My ajax code execute MoveController Acton method via Ajax passing form as a data.

```
 $('#btnmoveStructure').unbind('click').click(function () {    

var $form = $('#frmStructureMove');
var moveData = $form.serialize();
moveData = $('#frmStructureMove').serialize();
alert(moveData);

var winMoveStructure = $("#MoveStructureModalWindow").data("kendoWindow");


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    cache: false,        
    url: '/StructureMove/StructureMove',
    // dataType:"json",
    //data: { "model": moveData, "form": moveData },        
    data: { "form": moveData },        
    success: function (results) {
        $('#btnmoveStructure').hide();           
        $('#MoveStructureModalWindow').html(results);
        console.log("Move window results in HTML ");

    },
    complete: function () {

    },
    done: function () {

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        var msg = "";
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
        } else if (jqXHR.status === 404) {
            msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
        } else if (jqXHR.status === 500) {
            msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            msg = 'Time out error.';
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
        } else {
            msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
        }
        console.log("failure : " + msg);
    }
});
```

How do I get value of radio button inside action method. current Request.Form["radioSource"] does return "yes which is wrong. The at loading radio button is set to "Yes" value always.

when run form[0] returns following values

hdnStructureCode=0000641338&__RequestVerificationToken=MqBNaHfDzuRRkkvyp4tS716Fr4nRhlTANBASp3rJQYB2E1lpKLN40UuTW9e6a3caYIa2cCHCueouZbrKT7tcjc1mexSysWoXBi8P_J6gN_41&Code=0000641338&Description=Battery+String%2C+VRLA%2C+Century%2FYuasa%2C+UXH125-6%2C+6.00+V%2C+110.00+Ah&**radioSource=Yes**&radioDestination=&DestinationCode=DCP-SS-00001922&DestinationDescription=Batteries&chkReturnToSource=true&chkReturnToSource=false

I have highlighted radioSource value (yes) but how can I retrieve in MVC C3 action method inside. Please I am stuck as I tried every possible way. I can't use key value as this does not have one. it returns as queryString.

Could you please kindly tell someone where to fix this either ajax or my c# code

Thanks in advance

thusith

Comment: MVC is a concept edit your question to show that you use C#

Answer (score 0):

The value of the radio button might not be posting correctly probably because you have two elements with the same ID. Try giving unique IDs for both the radio buttons like this

```
@Html.RadioButton("radioSource", "Yes", true, new { id = "radioMoveAllYes", data_toggle = "tooltip", data_placement = "right", title = "Click to select", htmlAttributes }) Yes

@Html.RadioButton("radioSource", "No", false, new { id = "radioMoveAllNo", data_toggle = "tooltip", data_placement = "right", title = "Click to select", htmlAttributes })  No
```

This is worth a try at least. Either way, you should never have two elements with the same ID.

Comment: Thanks sagar1025 I will check your suggestions.